# Does freezing a Li-ion battery have any effect on its ability to hold charge?

Tags: battery-life, battery, lithium-ion

Ok. [I've](http://www.heritage-tech.net/746/reviving-a-dead-notebook-battery/) [heard](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Your-Cell-Phone-Battery-Last-Longer) [this](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=345524) [rumor](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080927035216AAqJiv6) [at](http://sodoityourself.com/reviving-laptop-batteries/#comment-11749) [least](http://hackaday.com/2005/08/26/how-to-laptop-resurrection-and-upgrade/) [100](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110110143513AA2m2oz) [times](http://help.com/post/199431-is-it-true-that-if-you-put-a-lithiu). I can't find any information to substantiate it or any serious research done it. Is it a total rumor, or is there truth to it? Has there ever seen a study on this?

Comment: The only reason I have froze a battery, Lion, Nmh, Nicad, is to cool it down so it will charge properly, overheated batteries of this type will either not charge or not charge fully. I have noticed when I freeze them, they tend to charge faster, I have not timed it though. Interesting question.

Answer (score 3):

There was a [related study](http://bit.ly/li-ion-tests) that tested cycles at different temperatures.

One finding was that the cells in the cold cycle tests (0°C) lost capacity, but when they were brought back to 20°C the capacity recovered. The report points out that **when the cells were maintained** at a low state-of-charge, the *capacity loss was less severe* but those cells did not recover capacity when brought to 20°C.

I don't know at what temperature Li-ion cells will freeze, but if you were thinking about icebox temps, yes it has an effect. They will not lose as much capacity as they would at room temperature or elevated temperatures, but some will be lost.

Comment: The question is if they will retain charges better after they've been frozen. The allegation is that if a batter -- incapable of holding a charge -- is frozen, the battery can be brought back to life by freezing it.